# urlencode in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, urlencode

```
$str = preg_replace("'\(look: (.{1,80})\)'Ui",
             "(look: <a href=\"dict.php?process=word&q=\\1\">\\1</a>)",$str);
```

i want to encode url, but how can I do that?

can i use urlencode() function in preg_replace?, something like that,

```
$str = preg_replace("'\(look: (.{1,80})\)'Ui",
            "(look: <a href=\"dict.php?process=word&q=\\1\">\\1</a>)",$str);
```

do you have any idea about encoding url in preg_replace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), which allows you to produce the replacement string by running code directly:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    "'\(look: (.{1,80})\)'Ui",
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return \'(look: <a href="dict.php?process=word&q='.urlencode($matches[1]).'">'.
          $matches[1].'</a>)\';'
    ),
    $str);
```

If you use PHP >= 5.3, you can make the above a bit less painful:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    "'\(look: (.{1,80})\)'Ui",
    function($matches) {
        return "(look: <a href=\"dict.php?process=word&q=".urlencode($matches[1])."\">".
               $matches[1]."</a>)";
    },
    $str);
```

Comment: thanks, and I think you forgot to change preg_replace as preg_replace_callback

Comment: The first code extract is missing some escapes of single quotes in return statement, should be
`'return \'(look: <a href="dict.php?process=word&q=\'.urlencode($matches[1]).\'">\'.
          $matches[1].\'</a>)\';'`

Comment: Great acknowledgement~!